# Execution failed for task ':app:generateSafeArgsDebug' part '' is keyword

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-graph

After a merge, Android Studio started showing the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: part '' is keyword
```

I'm aware this error it's related with some navigation graph, but all the graph xml files seems alright. Android Studio gives no further details.

This is the complete stack trace:

````
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: part '' is keyword
    at com.squareup.javapoet.Util.checkArgument(Util.java:64)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.<init>(ClassName.java:49)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.<init>(ClassName.java:43)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.get(ClassName.java:201)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.java.JavaTypesKt.typeName(JavaTypes.kt:191)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.java.ClassWithArgsSpecs.generateParameterSpec(JavaNavWriter.kt:513)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.java.ClassWithArgsSpecs.setters(JavaNavWriter.kt:319)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.java.JavaNavWriter.generateDirectionsTypeSpec$navigation_safe_args_generator(JavaNavWriter.kt:178)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.java.JavaNavWriter.generateDestinationDirectionsTypeSpec(JavaNavWriter.kt:77)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.java.JavaNavWriter.generateDirectionsCodeFile(JavaNavWriter.kt:65)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.java.JavaNavWriter.generateDirectionsCodeFile(JavaNavWriter.kt:57)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.NavSafeArgsGenerator$generate$1.invoke(NavSafeArgsGenerator.kt:66)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.NavSafeArgsGenerator$generate$1.invoke(NavSafeArgsGenerator.kt:74)
    at androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator.NavSafeArgsGenerator.generate(NavSafeArgsGenerator.kt:80)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.ArgumentsGenerationTask.generateArgs(ArgumentsGenerationTask.kt:74)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.ArgumentsGenerationTask.doFullTaskAction(ArgumentsGenerationTask.kt:109)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.ArgumentsGenerationTask.taskAction$navigation_safe_args_gradle_plugin(ArgumentsGenerationTask.kt:98) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that one argument in a graph had an empty argType.

Wrong code:

```
<argument
    android:name="monetaryAccounts"
    app:argType=""
    android:defaultValue="string" />
```

Correct code:

```
<argument
     android:name="monetaryAccounts"
     app:argType="string"
     android:defaultValue="" />
```